# Making part of JavaScript regex optional

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following original strings:

```
# Original strings
js/main_dev.js # This one is just to check for false positives
js/blog/foo.js
js/blog/foo.min.js
```

I'd like to run a substitution regex on each one and end up with this:

```
# Desired result
js/main_dev.js
js/blog/foo_dev.js
js/blog/foo_dev.min.js
```

So basically, add `_dev` before `.min.js` if it exists, if not, before `.js`. That should only apply on strings that start with `js/blog` or `js/calculator` and end in `.js`.

I initially started out with `(js\/(?:blog|calculators)\/.+)(\.min\.js)$` as a regex and then `$1_dev$2` as substitution. That works for my third string, but not my second obviously as I am "hard" looking for `.min.js`. So I figured I'd make `.min` optional by throwing it in a non capture group with a `?` like this: `(js\/(?:blog|calculators)\/.+)((?:\.min)?\.js)$`. Now this works for my second string but my third string is all out of whack:

```
js/main_dev.js # Good
js/blog/foo_dev.js # Good
js/blog/foo.min_dev.js # Bad! _dev should be before the .min
```

I've tried many permutations on this, including simply doing `(\.min\.js|\.js)` but to no avail, all result in the same behavior. Here is a Regex 101 paste with the "bad" regex: https://regex101.com/r/bH3yP6/1

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try throwing a `?` after the `+` at the end of your first group (the non-capturing one) to make it lazy (non-greedy):

`(js\/(?:blog|calculators)\/.+?)((?:\.min)?\.js)$`

`(?:\.min)?` is optional and `.+` is greedy, so `.+` was capturing `.min`.

https://regex101.com/r/bH3yP6/3